# stop record from being saved if all empty strings in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation

I currently have a nested forms model. The nested forms for the paperclip attachments work fi and don't populate the DB with blanks, but another one I have for quotes always saves one blank quote along with my main model when I create a new one. How can I just have it silently fail and bypass writing this to the db? It's an optional field so I don't want to give them an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following option on accepts_nested_attributes

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :quotes, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

If you want to be more specific about when the record is considered blank, :reject_if also can take a proc.